# Tornado analyse requests

Tags: python, tornado

with tornado I would like be able to fully analyse web requests.

This is the request

```
curl -vk _POST http://127.0.0.1:3000 -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data "testObject=20"
```

with that code

```
import time, threading
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import sys

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        print('get message:')
        print(str(self.request.body))
        self.write(self.request.body)

    def post(self):
        print('post message')
        print(str(self.request.body))
        self.write(self.request.body)

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

def startTornado():
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(my_port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

def stopTornado():
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_port = 3000
    print('app is listening on port',str(my_port))
    t = threading.Thread(target=startTornado)
    t.start()
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.01)
        # signal : CTRL + BREAK on windows or CTRL + C on linux
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            stopTornado()
            t.join()
            sys.exit()
```

I get just

```
b'testObject=20'
```

In order to be able to correctly react to the encodings, content type,data etc. How I use tornado for that ? is there anything else in python I could use ?

Answer (score 1):

In tornado `request.body` is always the raw body data. Form-encoded data is parsed into the `arguments` structures and usually accessed with methods like `self.get_argument('testObject')`.

Comment: ok thanks. there is no such thing like self.arguments ? would self.request miss anything which is in the webcall ?

Comment: It's a little inconsistent, but you can access all the arguments via `self.request.arguments`, or individual arguments with `self.get_argument`. There are other variations too; see the docs for details.

Comment: I have to admit I am sometimes lost in the tornado docs. If you like could you point me to the right path

Comment: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=get_argument#input